# Suit for very fast running

Tags: physics

Using the modern technology, **is it possible to have a suit which will allow to run at Mach 12** (~4km / s)? For simplicity let's ignore the landscape issues (i.e. "what happens if I run into a building")

My concerns are:

- Air resistance. At such speed it will probably just rip the suit apart
- Heat. Related to the previous one. How not to be cooked alive?

EDIT: *Let's put aside the question of how do I run that fast (I have a jet booster? I push the ground back with an insane kinetic force? doesn't matter)*

Comment: I think your runner will need a body-sided shield made of the same material as the heat plating on space shuttles.  :) Shuttle is going at 9km/s, but it goes through upper atmosphere that is a lot less dense. A crack in the heat plating of Atlantis has destroyed it. If your runner has armor instead of a shield, it will have cracks in it to enable motion. But a shield will create a zone of air that is moving at the same speed as the runner.

Comment: Is your runner a Flash or Superman who is naturally resistant to hazards of moving at Mach 12, or it's a more normal (but fast) human who won't like to get heated over 40C?

Comment: A space suit will allow running at much faster speeds, if the Mission Commander permits running within the capsule.

Comment: If you had a suit made of nano Kevlar, graphene And maybe an eyepiece made of a palladium glass alloy
topped of with ceramic tiles than yes you could
But my main concern is how would you stay conscious. At Mach 4 you would pass out and your brain couldn’t register your surroundings at that speed the fastest possible a human can run is 40 mph so you would need some futuristic shock absorbers and a power source like an arc reactor (doesn’t exist) I get the kinetic energy thing but staying on the ground seems difficult. It’s theoretically possible but lots of obstacles in the way

Comment: Might want to read *ManFac* by Martin Caidin.  His response to what TV did to his *Cyborg* (short version -- no, you can't run even 100 km/hr, even with mechanical aid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One cannot run faster than how fast he can push his feet backward.

This leads to the main showstopper for this idea: whoever wears this would have to move his foot back at 4 km/s and then call it back at the same velocity.

Assuming that this happens in 0.1 second (10 steps per second is about what an Olympic sprinter does), it means that his leg would be accelerated at 80000 $m/s^2$, or about 1000 gee.

That's more than enough to pull any limb away.

[Randall Munroe](https://what-if.xkcd.com/133/) has also a nice page on a similar thing:

> Really, the numbers are just telling us what common sense told us from the start: You can't grab hold of something while going 100 mph,

Comment: I initially thought this the case, but couldn't think of how to explain it. Was halfway through an answer comparing the OP's desire with our current technological achievements to showcase what they're trying to accomplish, but this is much better.

Comment: obviously the steps would have to be a lot faster even. in 0.1 sec the runner covers a distance of 400m. and the return swing has to be twice the speed.

Comment: Well, I understand this, but again, this is why I didn't want to delve deep into discussion of how do I move that fast. Maybe I push the ground back with an insane kinetic force provided and so I don't have to move my legs nearly as fast/frequent (thus running would be like "very long jumping near the ground"). Anyways, these are some points to think about

Comment: Indeed, most "powered armor" concepts revolve around enhancing human endurance rather than speed. If the person could run at 10mph for hours at a time, the advantages to the military would be enormous. Russia even developed such, but the boots were difficult to learn to use, and had other issues besides. http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/820398.stm The top speeds reported in that article were also quite high compared to experimental results, if I remember.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many more concerns not related to landscape issues, like

- what if you get some small stone in your face (maybe some sand dust is already enough to kill someone). Solution could be a suit that fully covers you.
- air resistance will not only rip your suit (depends on the fabric), but how can someone get to that speed without of an external power source (i.e. a suit that 'runs' you).
- Keeping yourself balanced with such speed also is very hard, unless the suit has features to keep you stabilized.
- Also I assume your feet or even shoes do not touch the ground, but the suit has its own ground contact.

Assuming you will have a suit with external power supply and stabilization, and a suit that fully covers you, than the same requirements apply as to a vehicle (except for the wheels). The 'suit' will not be ripped apart if you make it from some metal, and in that case heat is neither; a plane can go fast, and otherwise the heat panels of a space shuttle can be used).

Comment: The obstacles aren't an issue (at least not in the context of my question, so I specified it there). But those are interesting insights, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this person is a speedster-type superhero and could actually run that fast, there is no modern material that could be made into a classical Flash-esque skinsuit and survive. The only realistic materials able to withstand sustained Mach-12 speeds at sea level altitudes would be ablative ceramic thermal tiles, such as those used on the Space Shuttle or other reentry-capable spacecraft.

Most practical metals would probably melt at those speeds and temperatures too. There was a persistent heat problem when engineers were developing the SR-71 Blackbird and trying to prevent it from melting. The SR-71 only flew at Mach ~3.5 maximum. In short, your superhero would need some future-material for their suit, project some sort of invulnerability shell, or be a walking spacecraft.